# Using Git safely with multiple people

Tags: git, github

Recently I've been trying to encourage the use of Git within my team so we can all learn about it and get the benefits of true version control, not just making a dated folder as a backup.

I feel I understand the basic commands:

- Git clone: clones a repo to a local repo
- Git fetch: gets changes but doesn't apply them to your local working directory
- Git merge: a bit hazy here...
- Git pull: performs a Git Fetch and attempts a Git Merge
- Git push: pushes changes to remote server

My only confusion is: if I have unstaged changes, will a pull destroy these changes forever?

Should I either do a Git Stash, Git Pull, then Git Stash apply or should I commit my local changes, do a pull then push my local changes?

What is the correct approach?

I ask because if I'm to be working with multiple people via Git, how can I ensure I don't ruin things?

Comment: git will not allow to pull before comminting your local changes.

Comment: If a pull would destroy those changes then the pull won't complete, it will complain and stop.

Comment: Other than that I suggest you find a good book or set of tutorials (videos), there's a lot of information out there, and "best approach" depends on the person answering which makes it a very low quality answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Additionally, git can run entirely local, which means you can create a "server" repository in one folder, and clone it into two "client" repositories, then simulate what would happen if you do X and Y, so experiment, that's the **best** way to learn.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: The "local" git server might have problems with access rights to the internal bare repository, though, if used by multiple users.

Comment: Look at a site like “think-like-a-git.net” to get a better handle on git basics (especially the underlying model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of code commit :

If you are taking a pull from branch where everybody is working, then it is  crucial that your code should not affect others when push code next time.
In case of code stash:

It is advisable to create separate branches for own uses then merge it with main branch. This is the best practice people follow. It can save your code to delete as well. Next time you take a pull in your branch from main branch,your code will get merged with pulled code,so you don't have to delete your code.